# How to add support for PCIe bridge to coreboot on Baytrail SoC

Tags: c, intel, firmware, uefi

I Compiled Coreboot with Seabios and Tianocore payload on Baytrail SoC.
I want to use a [PCIe bridge](https://www.amazon.co.uk/IOCrest-Ports-Extension-Switch-Multiplier/dp/B075KNH1GM) to convert a PCIE-x1 to 2 PCIE-X1 connectors
but booting FreeBSD won't show any active bridge.

The [Baytrail SoC documentation](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/612/atom-e3800-family-datasheet-1522396.pdf#3202) states that a register called [SLCTL_SLSTS](https://github.com/coreboot/coreboot/blob/master/src/soc/intel/baytrail/include/soc/pcie.h#L43) should be
set in order to activate the bridge support but I don't know how to set such flag
on coreboot.

- Is it possible to use PCIe bridge on Baytrail SoCs?
- How one can add bridge support to coreboot if possible?